# Babel Plugin Module Alias not working w/ require('react')

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, infernojs

I am building an app with `electron-forge`, that is not really important other than that it extends the `.babelrc` to `.compilerc` in my project configuration.

I am using [infernojs / inferno-compat](https://www.infernojs.org/docs/guides/switching-to-inferno) and [babel-plugin-module-resolver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-module-resolver), to alias references to `react` to `inferno-compat`

.compilerc / .babelrc

```
"plugins": ["babel-plugin-inferno", "transform-async-to-generator", "transform-es2015-classes",
          ["module-resolver", {
                    "root": ["."],
                    "alias": {
                        "react": "inferno-compat",
                        "react-dom": "inferno-compat"
                    }
                }]],
```

So far this works fine w/ `.jsx` files, but when I install a package, like `react-bootstrap-modal` that has a line like:

Modal.js:

```
var react = require('react')
```

I an error:

> Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'react'
>       at Module._resolveFilename (module.js:485:15)

Answer (score 1):

Apparently [aliasing modules in packages does *not* work](https://github.com/tleunen/babel-plugin-module-resolver/issues/191), because Babel does not compile third party modules by default.

My workaround was to symlink `inferno-compat` to `react` and `react-dom`:

```
cd node_modules
ln -s inferno-compat react
ln -s inferno-compat react-dom
```

---

As a side note: Git works nicely with symlinks. If you check in these symlinks, Git will treat them as normal files and not resolve them.